# MySQL database connection not working

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

First time using an external database with android and i'm trying to set up the database connections. I created a basic table in the database just for testing purposes and am trying to connect and insert some data. This is my code:

```
public class DBInterface {
//TODO: Fix the database connections

    private Connection conn = null;
    private  Statement statement = null;



    public void connectToDatabase(){
        Log.d("myTag", "This is my messagestart");
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.**.***.***.***:3306", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD");
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES (15)");
            Log.d("myTag", "This is my message");


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Log.d("myTag", "SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            Log.d("myTag","SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            Log.d("myTag","VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

and I call it in the onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
         DBInterface db = new DBInterface();
         db.connectToDatabase();
         Log.d("myTag", "This is my message2");
```

No data is inserted but i also don't get any errors, i put the log messages in to try and see where it was getting to and the only output to the log is:

> 10-31 16:13:41.481 9918-9918/com.jacksteel.comp4 D/myTag: This is my messagestart
>
> 10-31 16:13:41.486 9918-9918/com.jacksteel.comp4 D/myTag:
>   This is my message2

Comment: try:  **conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**.***.***.***:3306/DBNAME", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD");**

Comment: @BerndBuffen nothing changed, same output

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but you never want to connect your app directly to your database. Instead you should write some scripts on your server to perform INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE , DELETE.

Your app will then send requests to these scripts to execute the queries.

Comment: This. Do this. Don't give people raw access to your database. At best, it will restrict your ability to make under-the-hood adjustments. At worst, it'll cause data loss and/or leakage.

Comment: it's just for a school project currently, I don't have the knowledge or time to do that yet.

Comment: Writing a php script only takes 5 min Well Its your decision you know... Is your mysql accessible remotely, you also use executeUpdate but it is an INSERT

Comment: @meda yeah mysql is accessible remotely and i used executeUpdate because that's what it said to use for inserting/updating data or any command that did not return anything

Answer (score 0):

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prijava</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>VISER twitter</h1><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Unesite email"> <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" placeholder="Unesite lozinku"> <br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="dugme" id="dugme" class="btn btn-sm ">Uloguj se</button>
        <div id="odgovor"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dugme").click(function(){
        let unetEmail=$("#email").val();
        let unetaLozinka=$("#lozinka").val();
        $.post("login.php",{email: unetEmail, lozinka: unetaLozinka}, function(response){
            $("#odgovor").html(response)
        })
    })
})
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['lozinka'])&&$_POST['email']!=""&&$_POST['lozinka']!=""){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $lozinka=$_POST['lozinka'];
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
    if(!$db){
        die("greska prilikom prijave na bazu, greska je ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $upit="SELECT * from korisnici where email='$email' and lozinka='$lozinka'";
    $rez=mysqli_query($db,$upit);
    if(mysqli_error($db)!=""){
        echo "greska pri izvrsavanju upita ".mysqli_errno($db).": ".mysqli_error($db);
    }else{
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rez)==1){
            while($red=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                $_SESSION['ime'] = $red['ime'];
                $_SESSION['prezime'] = $red['prezime'];
                $_SESSION['status']=$red['status'];
                $_SESSION['korisnikid']=$red['id'];
            }
            
            echo '<script>window.location.href = "posts.php";</script>';
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Uneti podaci ne odgovaraju ni jednom korisniku</div><br>";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}else echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Svi podaci moraju biti uneti</div><br>";
?>
```

**Posts.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['ime']." ".$_SESSION['prezime']." ".$_SESSION['status']."<br><a href='odjava.php'>Odjava</a> | <a href='administracija.php'>Administracija</a>";
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['lozinka']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['lozinka'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $lozinka=$_POST['lozinka'];
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
    if(!$db){
        die("greska prilikom prijave na bazu, greska je ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $upit="SELECT * from korisnici where email='$email' and lozinka='$lozinka'";
    $rez=mysqli_query($db,$upit);
    while($red=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez))
    echo "Korisnik: {$red['ime']} {$red['prezime']} {$red['status']}<br> ";
}
    ?>
        <form action="postInsert.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="post" id="post" placeholder="Unesite novi post" required> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name='dugme2' id="dugme2">Snimi post</button>
        </form>
        <h1 class="display-6">Postovi</h1>
        <?php
        $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
        $upit="SELECT postovivremek, post, ime, postovi_id, prezime from veza_korisnici_post";
        $rez=mysqli_query($db,$upit);
        while($red=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
            if($red['ime']==$_SESSION['ime']&&$red['prezime']==$_SESSION['prezime'])
            echo "<div class='siv'>{$red['postovivremek']}<br><b>{$red['post']}</b><br>{$red['ime']} {$red['prezime']}<br><a href='postDelete.php?postovi_id={$red['postovi_id']}' class='btn btn-danger btn-small'>Obrisi</a><br></div>";
        else echo "<div class='siv'>{$red['postovivremek']}<br><b>{$red['post']}</b><br>{$red['ime']} {$red['prezime']}<br></div>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        mysqli_close($db);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**administracija.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Belgrade');

$danasnjiDatum = date("Y-m-d");

$putanja_do_foldera = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\\njuska_sliko\logovi";


if (!file_exists($putanja_do_foldera)) {
    mkdir($putanja_do_foldera, 0777, true);
}


$naziv_datoteke = $danasnjiDatum . ".txt";

$putanja_do_datoteke = $putanja_do_foldera . '\\' . $naziv_datoteke;



    $fajl = fopen($putanja_do_datoteke, "a");


    $tekst = date("H:i:s") . " - Prijava korisnika '" . $email_korisnika . "'" . PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($fajl, $tekst);


    fclose($fajl);

    echo "Podaci su dodati u datoteku: " . $putanja_do_datoteke;

?>
```

**PostInsert.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
    if(!$db){
        die("greska prilikom prijave na bazu, greska je ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['dugme2'])){
        $idKorisnika=$_SESSION['korisnikid'];
        $post=$_POST['post'];
        $upit = "INSERT INTO postovi (idkorisnika, post) VALUES ('$idKorisnika', '$post')";
        mysqli_query($db,$upit);
        echo header("Location: posts.php");
    }
?>
```

**PostDelete.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
    if(!$db){
        die("greska prilikom prijave na bazu, greska je ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['dugme2'])){
        $idKorisnika=$_SESSION['korisnikid'];
        $post=$_POST['post'];
        $upit = "INSERT INTO postovi (idkorisnika, post) VALUES ('$idKorisnika', '$post')";
        mysqli_query($db,$upit);
        echo header("Location: posts.php");
    }
?>
```

**odjava.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    
    echo '<a href="index.php">Nazad na pocetnu</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me) whether your code solves the problem described in the question or if you are posting your code that does not work. Can you [edit] your answer and explain what the code does and how it resolves the problem described in the question?